# Webpack, Scss - add cdn server path before compilation

Tags: npm, webpack, sass

How do I add a cdn path variable into the styles.scss before compilation? I have a webpack 4 configuration that works fine for JS. The JS/CSS files are loaded correctly from the desired cdn url.

What I want to achieve is, that the project running on localhost will use a different cdn url for images/icons/fonts than the same web running on production.

My webpack config has these lines for setting the cdn domain:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    webUrl = 'https://cdn.project.com/';
}
else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    webUrl = 'http://localcdn.localhost/';
}
```

This code works well for JS/CSS files, but CSS always loads backgrounds/fonts using a relative path, which of course is the main domain and not the cdn.

Maybe just open the styles.scss and update the file manually before webpack compilation? Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of trial and error I found this solution for webpack 4. It may help someone trying to solve the same issue.

```
        {
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options : {
                        url : false,
                        sourceMap: devMode
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options : {
                        processCssUrls : false,
                        sourceMap: devMode,

                        data : "$cdnFolder: 'http://cdn.myweb.net/';"
                    }
                }
            ],
        },
```

This is a part of webpack.config.js, in the section:

```
module : {
  rules : {
```

This configuration makes the scss variable *$cdnFolder* available in every scss file. CDN link can be changed based on the current mode dev/prod/stage.

Comment: Another solution can be, use relative urls inside the css, and load the css itself from the cdn, that way the assets in the css will be relative to the css path.

Comment: @felixmosh I had it this way, but it always loaded the main domain. Doesn't it matter where the CSS was loaded and not from where?  Maybe I am wrong, but I was searching for this solution because relative urls didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you have a <base> tag in your html, this tag overrides that behaviuor

Comment: @felixmosh No base tag :)  Are you 100% sure that relative links in css are created with the css file's domain and not the main domain?

Comment: Yeap, I'm sure, think about that, for example, font-awesome, provides only css file, so how the browser knows the path to the font itself? it must be relative to that css file.

Comment: @felixmosh in that case I have no idea why it doesn't work in my code.. I have to expiremnt with it.  Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

For webpack 5, the config changed a little:

```
  {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options : {
                   additionalData : "$cdnFolder: '" + cdnUrl + "';"
                }
   }
```